# chillout/loungy background tune

Tags: music

hi,
i'm looking for a sample library or cheap license music to create a background tune for a production i just finished. desired style is electronic lounge/chillout. any recommendations?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

if you like something from my older works contact me, i will give it away for free http://soundcloud.com/formatnone

thou the style might be not so suitable for you...still...check it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Killer Tracks is pretty good! http://www.killertracks.com/

Answer (score 0):

[AudioJungle](http://audiojungle.net?ref=hectorlee) is a great source for such material. Well. The tracks aren't free but the prices are quite low when compared to buying an entire library. Preview the tracks to see if something suits you. There's also a free track every month and if you're lucky, it might be the track for you.